# How show some fields only when using WMSGetFeatureInfo?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, getfeatureinfo

How to show some important field only when using WMSGetFeatureInfo.I use [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html) example.
When I click on maps it show all the fields of attribute table.What part should I modify in above mentioned code.
Pls help me?
Any idea wellcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked through the [manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/index.html)? if so you seem to have missed this [section](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) which explains how to control the output of a getFeatureInfo request.

Comment: Actually I am not using nay templates .I use only that openlayers example.With in that code Is any method to do this?

Comment: no there is no way to do that at the client end